# Json DeserializedObject how do I call the returned values

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I call the values from the Wrapper items.  I assumed it would be for example items.SysName but no luck.  I am calling a query that returns a list of text in json format that is then filtered with the jsonConvert I am just unable to call the results but I can view that they are there in the debugger.  The end result is I will create a list of the SysName values and return said list.

```
public async Task<string> Table()
        {
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient client = GetClient())
                {
                    var response = client.GetAsync("unimportant");
                    response.Wait();
                    if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var result = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Wrapper items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(result);
                        
                        
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning(ex, $"Failed to retrieve requested Table |{ex.Message}");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return null;
            
        }
```

Wrapper class

```
public class Question
    {

        [JsonProperty("link")]
        public string Link { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class SysPackage
    {

        [JsonProperty("link")]
        public string Link { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class SysScope
    {

        [JsonProperty("link")]
        public string Link { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {

        [JsonProperty("rec_misc")]
        public string RecMisc { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("question")]
        public Question Question { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sys_mod_count")]
        public string SysModCount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sys_updated_on")]
        public string SysUpdatedOn { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sys_tags")]
        public string SysTags { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sys_class_name")]
        public string SysClassName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("published_ref")]
        public string PublishedRef { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sys_id")]
        public string SysId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sys_package")]
        public SysPackage SysPackage { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("inactive")]
        public string Inactive { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sys_update_name")]
        public string SysUpdateName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sys_updated_by")]
        public string SysUpdatedBy { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sys_created_on")]
        public string SysCreatedOn { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sys_name")]
        public string SysName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sys_scope")]
        public SysScope SysScope { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sys_created_by")]
        public string SysCreatedBy { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("misc")]
        public string Misc { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("order")]
        public string Order { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sys_policy")]
        public string SysPolicy { get; set; }
    }

    public class Wrapper
    {

        [JsonProperty("result")]
        public IList<Result> Result { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Image showing that results do show up.

[image: Image showing that results do show up.]

Comment: What do you mean? did you want to return the object?

Comment: The object is storing data I need to be able to access that data so for example the Json value sys_name = bla is stored in SysName which is inside the object each time in the 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 so I need items then [0] then SysName

Comment: so basically I need to store the Sysname of each in the object to a list and return that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`items` is a `Wrapper` which contains a collection of `Result`  : `items.Result`.

You can iterate through it to access the results one by one. One way to do it is by using a foreach loop

```cs
foreach (Result result in items.Result)
{
    string sysName = result.SysName;
}
```

You can also use LinQ to retrieve all of the sysNames

```cs
IEnumerable<string> sysNames = items.Result.Select(result => result.SysName);
```

If you only care about the first result, just use

```cs
Result result = items.Result.First();
string sysName = result.SysName;
```

PS :
Renaming `Wrapper.Result` to `Wrapper.Results` and `var items = ...` to `var wrapper = ...`  is more explicit about your data.

Comment: I tried both your foreach and IEnumerable it basically says at the .select point "Wrapper does not contain a definition for select and no accessible extension method select accepting a first argument of type wrapper could be found."  I'm assuming I might have to change the wrapper to something?

Comment: Oh sure, I forgot one thing, i'll editing my post now :)